# API's web, REST e Orientação a Objetos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, aplicação-web, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou começando a estudar API's web um pouco mais a fundo e fiquei um pouco em dúvida com a seguinte questão: trabalho com ASP.NET WebAPI e, portanto, com orientação a objetos. Tenho na minha solução um projeto de domínio contendo os tipos do domínio com seus comportamentos codificados neles e tudo mais.

O que acontece é que lendo sobre API's ouvi falar sobre o Richardson Maturity Model que categoriza as API's em quatro níveis:

- Nível 0 (RPC): Usamos o HTTP só como meio de enviar chamadas a funções no servidor. Temos só uma URI.
- Nível 1: Dividimos a aplicação em recursos e temos várias URI's, uma pra cada recurso, mas usamos ainda a URI pra descrever a ação a ser executada.
- Nível 2: Usamos os métodos do HTTP pra descrever a ação a ser executada em cada recurso e a ação não faz mais parte da URI.
- Nível 3: Uso de hypermedia pra dizer o que pode ser feito depois da ação a ser tomada.

Pelo que eu entendi do livro o ideal é ter o nível o maior possível. Acontece que me parece que ao atiginir o nível 2 o uso da orientação a objetos fica comprometido.

O que eu já li por aí, foi algumas pessoas dizendo que o REST e o HTTP serve só pra transferir estado de recursos e isso vai contra a ideia da orientação a objetos de modificar o estado dos objetos através dos métodos deles invés de simplesmente acessar os campos. Ou seja, usando orientação a objetos direito, ao invés de acessar os campos de um objeto, executamos um método e como consequência o estado do objeto pode mudar. Uma API que já está no nível 2 do RMM, por outro lado, modificaria o estado de um recurso enviando uma requisição PUT que simplesmente trocaria os valores dos campos.

Pesquisei um pouco sobre isso e vi um vídeo do Jim Webber falando que a ideia é que usemos o HTTP pra realmente transferir documentos entre o client e o servidor mas sendo que essas transferências tenham efeitos colaterais provocando ações no servidor. Pensei um pouco sobre isso e queria saber se entendi corretamente a forma de conciliar Web API's, REST e Orientação a Objetos.

O que pensei foi o seguinte: supondo que o sistema precise gerenciar contas bancárias e tenha um tipo `Account` representando uma conta e um tipo `Transaction` representando uma transação. Temos então um método no tipo `Account` que recebe outra conta e um valor e realiza uma transferência. Seria algo como:

```
Transaction transferTransaction = account.Transfer(anotherAccount, amount);
```

Isso, pelo que eu entendo, seria o jeito de fazer isso na orientação a objetos. Não vamos lidar com os campos dos tipos diretamente, vamos deixar a lógica de negócio dentro dos tipos do domínio.

O ponto, entretanto, é o seguinte: ao chegar no nível 2 do RMM me parece que eu teria que fazer o seguinte na Web API: criar um resource `transaction` representando uma transação e então realizar um POST que cria uma transação enviando os dados das contas envolvidas e do valor. Algo como:

```
POST /api/transactions HTTP/1.1
Headers

{
    "originAccountId": "1",
    "destinyAccountId": "2",
    "amount": "50"
}
```

Daí no servidor teríamos um método mais ou menos assim (bem simplificado, sem tratamento de exceções ou outras coisas):

```
public IHttpActionResult TransferFunds([FromBody] TransferDto transferDto)
{
    Account originAccount = accountRepository.Get(transferDto.originAccountId);
    Account destinyAccount = accountRepository.Get(transferDto.destinyAccountId);
    Transaction transferTransaction = originAccount.Transfer(destinyAccount, transferDto.amount);
    transactionsRepository.AddTransaction(transferTransaction);
    return Created(location, transferTransaction);
}
```

Dessa forma, temos resources, usamos os métodos HTTP, mas ainda assim deixamos a lógica de negócio encapsulada no domínio. A ideia é que transferimos uma representação de uma transação pro servidor e como efeito colateral desse envio de documento, o servidor realiza ações no domínio da aplicação.

É essa realmente a ideia pra trabalhar com Web API's, REST e Orientação a Objetos? Existe nisso que eu fiz algum problema? Existem outros problemas pra conciliar REST e Orientação a Objetos?

Comment: Não entendemo muito do assunto e o que vou falar não está diretamente relacionado com a pergunta. Tem duas coisas que você está tentando alcançar e vou te dar um conselho que é mais importante que a resposta. Não se apegue a conceitos, tecnologias, metodologias, etc. E daí se não fizer orientado a objetos? Usar algo deve ter um motivo. E daí se não atingiu o nível de maturidade que alguém definiu? Faça o que tem que fazer, faça do jeito correto, faça atender as necessidades. Não se apegue a isso ou aquilo. Não estou dizendo que não possa estudar e talvez aplicar essas coisas, só não se apegue.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, acho que é por aí mesmo. Uma vez eu li mesmo que REST impõe um conjunto de itens que a API precisaria satisfazer, mas que é mais importante conhecer as consequências de cada item e usar só aquilo que realmente é importante pro projeto invés de tentar fazer a API ser 100% RESTful. Com relação a Orientação a Objetos, eu costumo tentar aplicar os conceitos na medida que da pra reduzir dependências e facilitar testes e manutenção do código depois, mas já vi que em alguns casos também não da pra fazer isso 100%. Obrigado pelo conselho!

Comment: Sua pergunta não deixou muito espaço para resposta, então cabe num comentário: Sim, coordenar objetos de negócio desenhados segundo orientação a objetos para responder a uma requisição REST é uma boa idéia. Não, não existe nenhum problema no que você fez. E não, conciliar REST ou RESTful e Orientação a Objetos não tem nenhum problema natural mas podem nascer problemas se os conceitos forem confundidos - REST é apenas uma fachada de serviços; o que tem por baixo pode ser resolvido com diversos paradigmas, inclusive com orientação a objetos.

Comment: Discordo um pouco de @bigown acho que devemos sim sempre utilizar praticas e paradigmas. Utilizar a ideia de que fiz do jeito que fiz porque não "cabe" determinada pratica com o requisito, muito provavel que sua compreensão ou seu modelo pode ser melhor pensado. Quanto a resposta coloquei como resposta para poder utilizar exemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito bem colocado  @Leandro e acho que isso é o que gera dúvidas em muita gente. É perfeitamente possível os dois mundos coexistir principalmente pq o OO ficará em seu domínio guardando a lógica de negócio.
O problema é que se gera confusão e acaba se pensando que um resource normalmente é um modelo do seu domínio, para algumas situações sim, mas ele é apenas uma representação de seu domínio.

Poderíamos refletir e gerar o seguinte resource

```
POST /api/accounts/{id}/transactions HTTP/1.1
Headers

{
    "destinyAccount": "2",
    "amount": "50"
}
```

Sua solução também está boa. Mas o principal é você saber que nem sempre um modelo é um recurso assim que nem sempre um recurso estará ligado a um modelo.